# Хранение данных в mysql

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся с таким вопросом

Есть база данных, есть таблица.

В этой таблице отражены записи товаров, кроме того, в этой таблице есть еще и сами категории товаров. Всегда думал что разные сущности нужно распихивать по разным таблицам.

Меня уверяют, что это нужно для более гибкой работы и для каких то непонятных вещей, которые нельзя сделать или очень трудно при разделении на категории и товары. Может кто пояснить?

Comment: Мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо, очень обширный ответ

Comment: *Может кто пояснить?* лучше всего сможет пояснить свои слова тот, кто их сказал.

Comment: он не может их пояснить, потому что это очень серьезные вещи которые, вот так просто моя голова не догонит

Comment: @ruslik, значит, не стоит брать дурного в голову.

Comment: Категория товара это не отдельная сущность

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе недостаточно конкретики. Поэтому попробую пролить свет "телепатически" (угадывая на основании личного опыта). :)
Если категории есть еще в отдельной таблице - вполне возможно, что это денормализация, которая делается для снижения нагрузки, чтобы убрать лишние JOIN запросы.
А если категории товаров помимо этого не содержатся в отдельной таблице и хранятся только прямиком в таблице товаров, то фиг его знает.
Я когда-то делал что-то подобное для того, чтобы эти категории могли вноситься самим пользователем.
Твоя голова способна догнать общую концепцию подхода, а вот детали конечно же тебе непостижимы до тех пор, пока сам не напишешь что-то эдакое. Поэтому спрашивай автора.

Answer (score 1):

В моем понимании, ты должен проектировать таблицу(ы) так, как считаешь нужным.
Напомню, ты можешь реализовать между элементами отношения:

1. Один к одному (Товар и  его штрих код и т.д.)
2. Один ко многим (Товар и отдел супермаркета, где этот товар по умолчанию расположен. В одном отделе может быть множество товаров, но всякий товар может расположен только в одном отделе.)
3. Многие ко многим. (К примеру товар и список поставщиков. Всякий поставщик поставляет множество товара и всякий товар может иметь более двух поставщиков).

"***Категории товаров***" - вещь не очень понятная. Если её понимать как: в*сякий товар может быть отнесен только к одной категории* - то отношение один ко многим. Если её понимать как: *всякий товар может быть отнесен к нескольким  категориям* - то это многие ко многим.

Предположим отношение один ко многим. В этом случае целесообразнее верстать в одну таблицу - для наглядности.

Предположим отношение - многие ко многим. В этом случае целесообразнее верстать в три таблицы. Довольно подробно об этом написали [здесь.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/)

Comment: коллеги, скажите пожалуйста, почему подчеркнутый текст (тег  <u> </u>) на стэковерфлоу не поддерживается? Может какой-то другой есть тег для поддержки  подчеркивания?

Comment: Как это "категории товаров" – вещь не очень понятная? А у Амазона что тогда? Наоборот, разделение товаров на категории является очень здравой идеей.

Comment: Я исчерпывающе пояснил. "Категории" в контексте SQL могут быть реализованы и как один ко многим, и как многие ко многим. Нужно элементарное уточнение.